# copy the attachments of a list item in CSOM

Tags: office-365, csom

I am copying list items from one list to another using the below function

```
protected void MigrateItem(ListItem item,ClientContext ctx,List targetList){
            ListItemCreationInformation listItemCreationInformation = new ListItemCreationInformation();
            ListItem listItem = targetList.AddItem(listItemCreationInformation);
            listItem["Title"] = item["Title"];
            //some other fields
            listItem.Update();
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        }
```

Here everything works just fine, but I am not able to see the attachments that were there in the source list. Which field should I use to get the attachments copied?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I found [this on  the internet](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1119844/Programatically-Copy-all-SharePoint-List-Items-to) and made some tweaks to copy to different list and the below code is working

```
private static void UpdateAttachments(ClientContext srccontext,
              ClientContext dstcontext, int srcItemID, int destItemID, string listName,string destListName)
        {
            try
            {
                //getting attachment from files
                Web srcweb = srccontext.Web;
                srccontext.Load(srcweb);
                srccontext.ExecuteQuery();
                string src = string.Format("{0}/lists/{1}/Attachments/{2}",
                                  srcweb.Url, listName, srcItemID);
                Folder attachmentsFolder = srcweb.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(src);
                srccontext.Load(attachmentsFolder);
                FileCollection attachments = attachmentsFolder.Files;
                srccontext.Load(attachments);
                srccontext.ExecuteQuery();

                if (attachments.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File attachment in attachments)
                    {
                        ClientResult<Stream> clientResultStream = attachment.OpenBinaryStream();
                        srccontext.ExecuteQuery();
                        var stream = clientResultStream.Value;

                        AttachmentCreationInformation attachFileInfo =
                                                     new AttachmentCreationInformation();
                        Byte[] buffer = new Byte[attachment.Length];
                        int bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        System.IO.MemoryStream stream2 = new System.IO.MemoryStream(buffer);
                        attachFileInfo.ContentStream = stream2;
                        attachFileInfo.FileName = attachment.Name;

                        Web destweb = dstcontext.Web;
                        List destlist = destweb.Lists.GetByTitle(destListName);
                        ListItem destitem = destlist.GetItemById(destItemID);
                        dstcontext.Load(destitem);
                        dstcontext.ExecuteQuery();
                        Attachment a = destitem.AttachmentFiles.Add(attachFileInfo);
                        dstcontext.Load(a);
                        dstcontext.ExecuteQuery();
                        stream2.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Log exception
            }
        }
```

Usage

```
protected void MigrateItem(ListItem item,ClientContext ctx,List targetList){
            ListItemCreationInformation listItemCreationInformation = new ListItemCreationInformation();
            ListItem listItem = targetList.AddItem(listItemCreationInformation);
            listItem["Title"] = item["Title"];
            //some other fields
            listItem.Update();
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            UpdateAttachments(ctx, ctx, item.Id, listItem.Id, ListName,DestListName);
        }
```